# Creating a custom webmail - What should i be aware of [INFRASTRUCTURE]?

Tags: php, email, dns, cloud, sendgrid

I'm trying to create a custom webmail, for one of our products, that has thousand of users.

We would like to create the webmail by our own, and let the user sends it by his/hers personal email (One that they already have, and is created)

I know that HubSpot CRM has something like that, but i don't know what i should be aware of, or how i can do it.

I know there I's a lot with spam, reputation etc, but i need some guidance. Can anyone help me out?

It could be awesome to do it with SendGrid integrated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You may start using a open source webmail client like [Roundcube](https://roundcube.net/) or [Rainloop](http://www.rainloop.net/). You can customize the client and use any third party MTA, or just use your current MTA in your own server.

If you want something more advanced, you could pipe all emails from a domain to your custom application and handle everything internally.